# Android Profiler timeline vs heap dump values

Tags: android, performance, android-profiler

I created a sample app and ran the Android Profiler. Just before getting a Java/Kotlin memory dump, I saw these numbers:

[image]

However, in the memory dump window I see these:

**View App Heap**
[image]

**View All Heaps**
[image]

Let's take a look at the numbers:
Native equals to 4.6 MB before the dump, and in the dump I see the native size equals to `92,041` or 91 kB (app heap) and `505,895` or 505 kB (all heaps). Neither of them is close to 4.6 MB. So I wonder how the graph numbers and the numbers in the heap dump are related.

Similarly, I don't understand how the retained size values from the dump are related to Others, Code, Stack, Graphics and Java in the timeline.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my assumption. The [Memory Overview](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory-overview) article says:

> When inspecting your app's heap, Android computes a value called the Proportional Set Size (PSS), which accounts for both dirty and clean pages that are shared with other processes—but only in an amount that's proportional to how many apps share that RAM

and the [explanation of how memory is counted](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler#how-counted) contains:

> The numbers you see at the top of the Memory Profiler (figure 2) are based on all the private memory pages that your app has committed, according to the Android system. This count does not include pages shared with the system or other apps.

So the app heap value of 8,372,986 (or ~8.3 MB) I saw **included** both dirty and clean pages that are shared with other processes whereas 5.4 MB of Java memory from the first screenshot includes private memory pages that my app has committed, according to the Android system. This count does not include pages shared with the system or other apps.